# I have a 2004 Subaru Forester that begins to shake violently (rear) when I accelerate over 40 mph, the shaking only persists during acceleration

Tags: vibration, shaking

I have a 2004 Subaru Forester that begins to shake violently (rear) when I accelerate over 40 mph, the shaking only persists during acceleration.
When I let off the gas it stops shaking.
I can't hear any noises, I used a fuse to switch it to front wheel drive, but the shaking persists. I changed my rear brake calipers and brakes, and just replaced the drive shaft due to the carrier bearing that had gone bad. Someone suggested that it may be a bad tire, if that were the case I can't see why the shaking would stop when I let off of the accelerator while still moving at a higher rate of speed (45mph). Also when I let off of the accelerator the vehicle begins to slow down more rapidly than what I think it should, it's almost as if I put the vehicle into low gear.
At this point I'm not sure what to look for that would cause the problem.
Any troubleshooting suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by checking all of the prop shaft components for wear and that any balancing weights are still attached -

- Universal joints
- Centre bearing and hanger
- Any rubber components

When you “replaced the drive shaft due to the carrier bearing that had gone bad”, did you have to split the shaft in two?  If so, did you put it back together in the correct alignment?